# UWP App Crash at Class1 c1 = new Class1(); saying - The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E

Tags: c++, c, uwp, windows-runtime

I am trying to create a library of fftool so that the uwp app doesn't have to launch a process to run FFmpeg exe out of the environment and yet able to run all command of fftool. so, for that
first, I created a static lib compiling fftool c code adding all the necessary linking and include
then I created a WinRT component in c++ to connect this library to my uwp app
so, again provided all the input, link, include and then added a reference to the static library to it.
since both of them are in the same solution.
so, I did not add a reference to the linker and include for the static library in the WinRT component
then for the test, I created a class calling a simple function that I added to c manually
but now whenever I try to create an object of that test class it throws an error saying
-The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

and this is all at runtime
while compiling and launching of the app in c# work fine.
but if I use the c++ app it crashes as it launches
and also I am new to c and c++ I didn't use the c/c++ before that so I am stuck at it and unable to understand what's wrong and I tried googling it but I am unable to find something

thanks

Comment: Some indirect required .dll cannot be loaded. Use procmon from sysinternals to check what it's looking for (you can filter by .exe, by file events, etc.).

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: ok so it looks like my app is unable to find FFmpeg core dll as avcodec, avfilter, etc so now I added
%systemroot%\System32\xcopy /y /s "$(SolutionDir)ffmpeg\$(Platform)\bin\" "$(SolutionDir)\App1\bin\$(Platform)\$(ConfigurationName)\AppX"
to my post-build event and now it was working fine 
Thanks for guidence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so it looks like my app is unable to find FFmpeg core dll as avcodec, avfilter, etc so now I added them to exe location and it worked ok